# Looking for an alternative SQL command to find the same values in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this command to find the same values in two tables when the tables have 100-200 records. But When the tables have 100000-20000 records, the sql manager, browsers, shortly the computer is freesing.

Is there any alternative command for this?

```
SELECT
distinct
names
FROM
table1
WHERE
names in (SELECT names FROM table2)
```

Comment: "IN" clause could be causing the db engine to perform an outer join (cross product) - a lot of extra work, unnecessary for the intended result. INNER JOIN avoids it, but for large row counts, indexes on the joined columns are essential for good performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple join will also do it.
make sure the column is indexed.

```
select distinct t1.names 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.names = t2.names
```

Comment: that is more powerful for my tables @randy  0.0012 seconds with "t1.names <> t2.names"

Answer (score 4):

Try with `join`

```
SELECT distinct t1.names
FROM table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.names = t1.names
```

Comment: you can speed things a lot by using indexes and joins in your queries

Comment: I hope OP has indexes on the tables

Comment: @Parado, IMO a join statement should always be explicit to ensure behaviour is fixed and transparent to the reader/maintainer of the code (similar style issue to the use of BETWEEN where the default behaviour is not clear from just reading the SQL)

Comment: thank you parado. "t2.names = t1.names" has no problem but "t2.names <> t1.names" is still slow or freesing.

Comment: @htaccess No problem you choose the best answer :) Don't forget you can vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT distinct t1.names
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tabl2 t2 WHERE t2.names=t1.names
)
```

Comment: You beat me to it. If you don't need data from table2, exists is the way to go.

Comment: Good solution!  Will the subquery perform well on mysql? Previously, I've tried to avoid doing references inside subqueries as the optimiser tends not to execute these well

Comment: @StephLocke: If there's an index on `names`, yes. I'm not a MySql expert, in sqlserver the `EXISTS` is more efficient than the `Join` and it's more readable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.names
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.names=t2.names
```

The use of the INNER JOIN ensures that there are only exact matches returned from both tables.  It should be relatively quick, but indexes may be required over the long term, especially if you're using them for other JOINs and GROUP BYs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Show `names` from **both** tables where there is a match

```
SELECT names
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT names
FROM   table2
```

This query will return duplicated values if there are any. If you only want distinct  values then try this but note that there will be an impact on performance

```
SELECT names
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT names
FROM   table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.names
FROM table1
INNER JOIn table2
ON table1.names = table2.names
Group By table1.names
```

Comment: when I use "table1.names = table2.names" there is no problem but "table1.names <> table2.names" makes it frozen @tkendrick20